# Dual Citizen (US-Iranian) seeking travel to Canada. Visited Iran 2011

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada, dual-nationality

I'm inquiring about a trip to Canada within the month. I am an natural-born American citizen with a dual citizenship of Iran by way of my Iranian parents. I have traveled to Iran once in 2011 with my Iranian passport.

I am worried I will run into trouble without preparing a bit more for the trip.

Comment: What sort of trouble?  Do you have evidence indicating that people in your situation would have such trouble?  Aside from delays and questioning at the border, I'm unaware of any, and I am also unaware of anything you can do in preparation to minimize the risk of such suspicion, or the impact.

Comment: There's nothing you can do if they choose to harass you. Just live your life.

Comment: Even if the correct answer is "relax, there's nothing to worry about", I don't blame the OP for asking.

Answer (score 3):

Canada and the US are two separate countries. It is the US that imposes restrictions for dual Iranian citizens, and even that does **not** apply to Canadians.

So just present your US passport or NEXUS card (or US passport card/enhanced driving licence if entering by land or sea), and you should have no problems, at least not due to your dual nationality.

Comment: Given that the US has detained for questioning at least one (somewhat prominent) Muslim natural-born American citizen, asking him about his religion, on entry into the US, the prediction that psyphr1 will have "no problems" seems unduly optimistic.

Comment: @phoog Changed the word to "should"

Answer (score 0):

Canada does not care about what other citizenships you hold. You qualify to visit Canada without visa because of your US citizenship, and being dual citizen makes no difference to that. You may possibly get a couple of extra questions at Canadian immigration if there is an Iranian stamp in your passport, but it will not be more than that.

Comment: "it will not be more than that": are you certain about that? Muhammad Ali Jr. was reported to have been detained for over two hours.

Comment: That was in the USA.

Comment: A "trip to Canada" most likely implies a return to the USA.